# Simple tool to recover old version of overwritten file

Tags: filesystem

I accidentally **overwrote** a small text file. I have no selectable TimeMachine snapshots - the "up" buttons are greyed out (note; tried Ctrl + Shift + C to remount but it makes no difference). Which is not surprising, as I have no external drive setup (and cannot because of security reasons).

There are a plethora of bad & free recovery apps that don't seem to work.

I'm wondering if there is any free & simple option available?

Comment: If you overwrote the file (I assume you saved the changes by mistake) and there's no backup in Time Machine, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Can you shed some light on the *"Time Machine isn't helping"* statement? What are you trying? What happens? Perhaps you could refocus the question on *that* issue, otherwise this as it's written is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Without a backup the chances of recovery are slim. And assuming that you have been using your Mac even after you deleted/overwrote the file the chances are even lower (because the freed space may have already been reused).